# SQLCipher - Decrypt database programmatically

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, sqlite-cipher

I'm using a .NET Core project in order to manage SQLite db encrypted and I would be able to create a db copy programmatically without encryption, but I'm not finding any sample code and I don't even know if this is possible.

I'm starting from scratch with the following project:
https://github.com/paragpkulkarni/SQLiteEncryptionUsingEFCore

Comment: Does it need to be generic to handle any DB with any scheme, or just for a particular scheme?

Comment: only for my db (particular scheme).

Comment: Easier to just load up all the tables to memory, then write them to the new DB unencrypted you have.

Comment: Any sample? I'm looking for sqlcipher_export() function which should accomplish my purpose but I'm unable to find some samples with ado.net and so on..

Comment: That will be off-topic right?

Comment: No. sqlcipher_export() would be the solution, but no sample code seems exists for ado.net or EF.

Comment: Ok, I've solved by combination beteewn SqliteConnection and standard documentation: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the final solution:

```
void DecryptDB(string sourceFilename, string destinationFilename, string password)
        {
            var connectionString = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = sourceFilename,
                Mode = SqliteOpenMode.ReadWriteCreate,
                Password = password 
            };

            using var cn = new SqliteConnection(connectionString.ToString());
            cn.Open();

            using var c = cn.CreateCommand();
            c.CommandText = @$"ATTACH DATABASE '{destinationFilename}' AS plaintext KEY '';";
            var r = c.ExecuteNonQuery();

            c.CommandText = @"SELECT sqlcipher_export('plaintext')";
            r = c.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: after using plaintext.db as destinationFileName i am getting below mentioned error :-----                                                                   

{SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database: plaintext.db
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x000cd] in <01c96d411fe34bd5940c99a56515582b>:0 
  at TundraNG.Core.DataStore.Handlers.ConnectionHandler.copyDB (System.String destinationFile, System.String FName) [0x00095] in }

Can you please help me on it..

Comment: Make sure your application  is able to create a new file on directory specified on destinationFilename parameter.

Comment: yes... permission is enabled to that folder. Also, I tried to manually create a file in the same location and then execute this code, but i am getting the same error. :(

Comment: Try to post your entire code snippet or even better try to open a new post.